# Qr reading with Opencv in real time Error "cv2.error: opencv(4.7.0)"

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I was developing an application to log in and out times using a Qr.

The system runs but when it is sent to register the hours the camera turns on and after a while this error appears.

> invalid qr code source points (expected: 'contourarea(src_points) > 0.0'), where > 'contourarea(src_points)' is 0 > must be greater than > '0.0' is 0.

**This is the part of the code as I have done where the error occurs**

```
while (capture.isOpened()):
        _,frame = capture.read()
        if (cv2.waitKey(1)== ord('s')):
            break
        qrDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
        data,bbox, rectifiedImage = qrDetector.detectAndDecode(frame)
        fecha = date.today()
        now = datetime.now()
        h=now.time()
        **if len(data) > 0:**                             #LINEA DONDE SALTA EL ERROR
            arr = data.replace("\'", "\"")
            arreglo = json.loads(arr)
            cedula = arreglo["Cedula"]
            nombre = arreglo["Nombre"]
            sql ='SELECT asi_id,asi_estado FROM asistencia WHERE asi_id = (select MAX(asi_id)from asistencia WHERE asi_cedula = %s)' 
            cursor.execute(sql,(cedula,))
            datos = cursor.fetchone()
            id = datos[0]
            estado = datos[1]
                
            if(cedula == cedula and estado == None or estado != "Entrada" ):
                asistencia.lbestado.setText("Entrada")
                estado1 = "Entrada"
                sqli = 'INSERT INTO asistencia(asi_cedula,asi_nombre,asi_hora_e,asi_fecha,asi_estado)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'
                datos = (cedula,nombre,h,fecha,estado1)
                cursor.execute(sqli,datos)
                db.connection.commit()
       
            else:   

                asistencia.lbestado.setText("Salida")
                estado2 = "Salida"
                sql2 = 'UPDATE asistencia SET asi_hora_s = %s, asi_estado = %s WHERE asi_cedula = %s AND asi_id = %s'
                d2 = (h,estado2,cedula,id)
                cursor.execute(sql2,d2)
                db.connection.commit()
 
            winsound.Beep(f,d)
            time.sleep(2)         
        else: 
            
            image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
            asistencia.lbvista.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

The objective is to keep the camera on all the time until the user decides to exit by closing the application.

Comment: You provide irreproducible code, but I can see you are not even checking if `frame` is a valid numpy array before processing it, you can start by adding that test.

Comment: Also, you are creating the `qrDetector` object every time you enter the `while` loop, instead of creating it just once and reusing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but you need to provide a [mre] including a sample image. Anyway it's very normal an OpenCV API throws an exception for an invalid input. Use ```try: ... except: ...```